# Wysiwyg editor with html5 tags

Tags: html, html5-video, wysiwyg, html5-audio

I'm trying to find some good wysiwyg editor for my site, that supports tags such as `<audio>` and `<video>`. So far i found only one that can add embeded video from youtube and vimeo. Are there any that support out of box those tags?

Answer (score 1):

I find [Mercury WYSIWYG tool](http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/) useful for HTML5 & CSS3 and it seems to meet your requirements.